# Installing Craft CMS 3 on hosting - Unsupported DB driver value

Tags: error, install, installation

i am trying to instal Craft CMS 3 on hosting and everytime it is going to fall on:

> 2019-07-05 16:33:55
>   [-][-][-][error][craft\base\ApplicationTrait::getIsDbConnectionValid]
>   There was a problem connecting to the database: Unsupported DB driver
>   value:  2019-07-05 16:33:55
>   [-][-][-][error][yii\base\InvalidConfigException]
>   yii\base\InvalidConfigException: Unsupported DB driver value:  in
>   /data/web/virtuals/136413/virtual/www/subdom/duetback/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/DbConfig.php:188

On installation page i can se:

> An internal server error occurred.

I have no idea, what is going on.

On localhost everthing goes fine with same settings.

Thank you!

Ondrej

Comment: How you confirmed that the database config and credentials in the .env file are correct, and that general.php is selecting the correct .env file?

Comment: I cannot get to installation, so i didnt fill the database config and credentials

How can I set in general.php reference to .env file?

Comment: Rename this file to .env and fill in the correct values: https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/master/.env.example, then they get pulled into `config/db.php` by using `getenv()` https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/master/config/db.php